# Does a simple document-based database exist?

Tags: java, database

Is there a database out there that I can use for a really basic project that stores the schema in terms of documents representing an individual database table?

For example, if I have a schema made up of 5 tables (one, two, three, four and five), then the database would be made up of 5 documents in some sort of "simple" encoding (e.g. json, xml etc)

I'm writing a Java based app so I would need it to have a JDBC driver for this sort of database if one exists.

Comment: That sounds like a description of the file system.  What's wrong with using files?

Comment: Could you simply use XML files?

Comment: Just wondering as there may be a way I can take advantage of still using hibernate/sql plus deal with concurrent users automagically for me.

Comment: What requirement prevents you from using a database?

Comment: Using a db that can be branched for two parallel bits of work that can be diffed and merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it for a bit, but [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org) has worked well in the past, and it's quite quick to set up:

"... offers a small, fast multithreaded and transactional database engine which offers in-memory and disk-based tables and supports embedded and server modes."

Comment: I have thought of using hsqldb however can it easily be split into files per table?  (see one of my comments about diffs and merges on the original post as to why I ask this)

Comment: Like this?  http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch06.html  "In a nutshell, Text Tables are CSV or other delimited files treated as SQL tables."

Answer (score 2):

1. [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB) and you can [use it](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Java) with java
2. [dbslayer](http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer) is also light weight with MySQL adapter. I guess, this will make life a little easy.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB works well (@zengr).  You may also want to look at MongoDB.

[Comparing Mongo DB and Couch DB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Comparing+Mongo+DB+and+Couch+DB)

[Java Tutorial - MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Also check http://jackrabbit.apache.org/ , not quite a DB but should also work.